# Eclipse on mac osx Mavericks

Tags: eclipse, macos

I want to use Eclipse to develop PHP on my Mac osx Mavericks. How ever I'm using a non-us keyboard and therefore I cannot type `>` sign which is really frustrating. The command for this is: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. I tried to find a solution in the `Preferences -> General -> Keys` but I could not make it work.

Any idea how can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Preferences->General->Keys order by Binding. Scroll till u find the Shift + Alt + X **+ ANY LETTER** you have to unbind all of them and then it will work.